# SQL: Daily Average of Logins Per Hour

Tags: sql

This query is producing counts of logins per hour:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, EVENT_DATETIME), 0), 
       COUNT(*)
  FROM EVENTS_ALL_RPT_V1
 WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'Login' 
   AND EVENT_DATETIME >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-03-17 00:00:00', 120) 
   AND EVENT_DATETIME <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-03-24 00:00:00', 120)
GROUP BY DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, EVENT_DATETIME), 0)
ORDER BY DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, EVENT_DATETIME), 0)
```

...with lots of results like this:

```
Datetime                 COUNT(*)
----------------------------------
2010-03-17 12:00:00.000  135
2010-03-17 13:00:00.000  129
2010-03-17 14:00:00.000  147
```

What I need to figure out is how to query the average logins per hour for a given day.  Any help?

Comment: The query you posted uses TSQL (used by SQL Server & Informix), yet you tagged this as MySQL and clearly returned a MySQL error 1064 - syntax error when you commented my answer...

Comment: Very sorry.  Was trying to help a friend but he failed to mention he was not working with mySQL and I foolishly assumed he was.  My apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the AVG aggregate function:

```
  SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(t.event_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), ':00:00.000') AS hr,
         COUNT(*) AS cnt,
         AVG(*) AS avg
    FROM EVENTS_ALL_RPT_V1 t
   WHERE t.event_name = 'Login'
     AND t.event_datetime BETWEEN '2010-03-24' AND '2010-03-17'
GROUP BY CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(t.event_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), ':00:00.000')
ORDER BY hr
```

The ORDER BY clause can use column aliases, but GROUP BY can not.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  Trying this I get:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' t.event_datetime), 0) AS hr,
         COUNT(*) AS cnt,
         AVG(*) AS avg
' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(m.countLogin) FROM
(SELECT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, EVENT_DATETIME), 0), 
   COUNT(*) as countLogin
   FROM EVENTS_ALL_RPT_V1
   WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'Login' 
   AND EVENT_DATETIME >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-03-17 00:00:00', 120) 
   AND EVENT_DATETIME <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-03-24 00:00:00', 120)
   GROUP BY DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, EVENT_DATETIME), 0)
   ORDER BY DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, EVENT_DATETIME), 0)) m
```

Note : Don't forget to give alias for new outer table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT AVG(cnt) FROM (
   your other query
)
```

But you need to name the second column `cnt` and maybe add a where clause that only looks at the given date.

Comment: That will give an average of all the hours returned, not per hour like the OP asks.

Answer (score 0):

This will select all the logins on the 18th of March per hour and then calculates the average.

```
SELECT AVG(count) FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) count
    FROM EVENTS_ALL_RPT_V1
    WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'Login' AND
    EVENT_DATETIME >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'2010-03-18 00:00:00', 120) AND
    EVENT_DATETIME <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'2010-03-19 00:00:00', 120)
    GROUP BY DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, EVENT_DATETIME), 0)
    ORDER BY DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, EVENT_DATETIME), 0)
)
```

Comment: That will give an average of all the hours returned, not per hour like the OP asks.

Comment: He already has the query to get the average login count per hour for every hour on a given day, he just set it to a week.

Answer (score 0):

For March 17th, 2010:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / 24
  FROM EVENTS_ALL_RPT_V1
 WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'Login' 
   AND EVENT_DATETIME >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-03-17 00:00:00', 120) 
   AND EVENT_DATETIME < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-03-18 00:00:00', 120)
```

Comment: That's assuming that people are logging in on every hour of the day.

Comment: @Fabian: No, it is not assuming they log in every hour. Rather, it is not *disregarding* hours where they do not login. The question title is Daily Average, not Average For Hours Where Users Logged In - my answer reflects my understanding of what the OP is asking for.